# Abscissa axis to $|x|$

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a differentiable mapping $f:R^2 \to R^2$ such that the abscissa axis goes into the function graph $y=|x|$?
$|x|$ doesn't differentiable at zero. But does this relate to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the "abcissa axis" is $\{(s,0):s\in\Bbb R\}$, yes. Let $$f(s,t)=(s|s|,s^2).$$